# "The specified module could not be found" when building a canvas with node-gyp

Tags: javascript, node.js, canvas, npm, building

I would like to install the https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/ module. I followed the windows installation instruction here

https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/wiki/Installation---Windows .

After typing: `npm install canvas` I got the following log:

```
Creating library F:\Stittch2\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.lib
and object F:\Stittch2\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.exp
Generating code
Finished generating code
canvas.vcxproj -> F:\Stittch2\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\\canvas.node
canvas@1.1.3 node_modules\canvas
└── nan@0.4.4
```

So I thought its compiled successfully, but when I do `require('canvas')` in `node` I'm getting the following error:

```
>node
>require('canvas')
Error: The specified module could not be found.
F:\Stittch2\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\canvas.node
  at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
  at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
  at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
  at require (module.js:380:17)
  at Object.<anonymous> (F:\Stittch2\node_modules\canvas\lib\bindings.js:2:18)
```

with 32bit Node/npm.

Seems that I'm not getting this error only with this module.

Comment: I uncovered a discussion on the topic at https://github.com/LearnBoost/node-canvas/issues/191. It did not solve the issue for me, but maybe you can confirm your dependencies. Perhaps your cause differs from mine?

Comment: So what is actually inside `F:\Stittch2\node_modules\canvas\build\Release\` ?

Answer (score 1):

does this fix solves your issue?

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4215

I think this has been fixed and Node.js 5.3.0 was released with it.

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/4281

Hope this helps!